# Using QGIS field calculator to replace null values with values from another field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have combined several shape files together in QGIS from some OSM data. I am trying to use the field calculator to set the null values of one attribute to have the values of another.

[image]

I am trying to make the null values of the landuse attribute equal the not null values of the Nature attribute

I think this is primarily an issue with my understanding with the QGIS field calculator syntax, I have tried using multiple conditional operators and cannot run the query due to this error

[image: first attempt at writing the query]

Parser Errors:
syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end

[image: Second attempt at writing query]

definitely do not understand the syntax

Comment: What is the actual expression you tried ?

Comment: This could be done using the "if" function or a "CASE" expression. Edit your question with the expression you tried so we can check for error

Comment: BTW SQL equivalent to "equal the not null" - is not null. "equal the null" - is null. Field names must be in double quotes "

Comment: edited the question to show some of the expressions i wrote

Comment: This could help you to better use the expression string builder : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#the-expression-string-builder. If needed the left part of the expression string builder has an help (you may need to click on the "show Help" button) with syntax and usage example for all function (just select a fonction on the list to display)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
case
    when "landuse" is null then "Nature"
    else "landuse"
end
```

Unless you actually have the string `NULL` in your field. Then replace `"landuse" is null` with `"landuse"='NULL'`

You can use select by attributes to find out.